# Typescript -- using symbols as object keys in ambient type declaration file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm having issues using symbols with TS ambient declaration files in Node. Here's a simplified example of what I'd like to do:

```js
// lib/symbols.ts
export const coolSymbol = Symbol('cool');

// ambient.d.ts
declare const SymbolKey: unique symbol;
interface CoolObj {
  [SymbolKey]: string;
}

// app.ts
import * as symbols from './lib/symbols';
const obj: CoolObj = {
  [symbols.coolSymbol]: 'my key is a cool symbol',
};

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": [
      "ES2017"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

With this example, I get typecheck errors in app.ts:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'symbol' can't be used to index type 'CoolObj'.
```

TS does not recognize that my CoolSymbol type and the type of the actual `coolSymbol` Symbol are the same, since all symbols are unique. Is there a fundamental incompatibility between Symbols, whose values are determined at runtime, and ambient TS files, which are not emitted as JS?

A couple of notes: using modules for types instead of an ambient file isn't a great option, since that would require a lot of refactoring of existing code (and there are a lot of types in use). This is a codebase that is primarily JS that we are slowly transforming into TS.

What I've tried:

- Specifying the type of `coolSymbol` like so, which results in "Type 'typeof coolSymbol' is not assignable to type 'typeof SymbolKey'."

```js
export const coolSymbol: typeof SymbolKey = Symbol('cool');
```

- Specifying the type of `coolSymbol` using `as`, i.e.

```js
export const coolSymbol = Symbol('cool') as typeof SymbolKey;
```

I'd also be fine with having the key be any old symbol, a la `[x: string]: string;` notation, but I hear that won't be available until TS 4.2 (maybe).